# ASP.Net MVC - Images taking a long time to load

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, optimization, asp.net-mvc-2

I have tested my pages in Firefox & IE and looking at Firebug in Firefox for some reason some images are taking a long time to load.  They are not very big in comparison to the ones which are loading quicker.

Attached is a screenshot of Firebug.

I especially notice it in IE with the progress bar at the bottom of the page, it just sits there saying loading image...[image]

Could it be the path or something which is http://localhost:49211/Content/_layout/images/bg-footer.png for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are running the site in VS (using Cassini) this is really slow, I had the same issue. I used Chrome, as it shows when the browser makes a requests to the images and file, which showed a large delay on Cassini delivering them.

if this is a case, try putting you site on the local IIS (if you have an instance). the site should run a lot faster.

Comment: Wow! That's amazing and quite worrying.

Comment: Yep, don't trust Cassini. Now with the introduction of IIS Express, there is no need for it anymore.

Comment: Do you recommend setting up VS to connect to a IIS setup rather than Cassini then

Comment: I think its up to you, just do not do performance measurements using Cassini. As RPM1984 mentioned there is a IIS express, this allows more control over the dev web server, or you can set up VS to use IIS. its up to you... PS (one side note) remember to alter the web.config file to have debug = false for relase

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the number of available connections. It is just sitting there since it is waiting for a connection.

With older browsers there was a limit of 2 connections from the browser to a site.

Comment: I think so, if not you could map the name localhost to external IP address in the HOSTS file and there would be no protection from DOS attacks.